# Getting following error while running application

Tags: c#, .net, qtp

I have an application developed in C Sharp, which is executed in QTP but i get the following error:

> Cannot identify the object "2" (of class WinObject). Verify that this object's properties match an object currently displayed in your application.

Can anyone help me resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If the application is developed in C# make sure you have the .NET addin loaded, then the object should be `SwfObject` rather than `WinObject`.

In any case use the object spy to point at the control you think should match the test object in the test and see how its properties differ (you can also use the **update from application** button from the object repository).